# What method for regression on percent data?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, modeling, multinomial-distribution

I would like to predict/model a repartition between 3 classes (A,B,C). 
I have a pool of person, and for each pool I have a repartition : A+B+C = 100%

this could be my dataset :

```
  ID var1 var2  A  B  C
1  1  yes  yes  6 77 17
2  2  yes   no 46  5 49
3  3  yes   no 24 35 41
4  4  yes   no 73 18  9
5  5   no  yes 76 12 12
6  6   no   no 97  2  1
7  7   no  yes 64  8 28
8  8   no  yes 61  5 34
```

I can also (if it is easier) combine the A and B classes :

```
  ID var1 var2 AB  C
1  1  yes  yes 83 17
2  2  yes   no 51 49
3  3  yes   no 59 41
4  4  yes   no 91  9
5  5   no  yes 88 12
6  6   no   no 99  1
7  7   no  yes 72 28
8  8   no  yes 66 34
```

What kind of method could I use to predict the repartition between A, B or C?

Comment: I you normalize the counts to probabilities, you can probably use Dirichlet regression for this. I've never use it myself but I've been looking for an excuse to try it. The case with two classes reduces to beta regression

Comment: You can probably also use multinomial regression as well. I imagine there's a connection between the multinomial and Dirichlet models but I don't want to speculate on exactly what that connection might be